# Present View Controller partially visible with base view controller while open the app from notification window

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios10, presentviewcontroller

I'm looking to displaying another controller while still partially showing the parent container. When open from notification window the screen appears partially for a second, it happens only in iOS 10. I have attached the screenshot link. Please can anyone tell me how to fix this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U9G6.jpg

```
ConfirmationController *confirmVC = (ConfirmationController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:PCConfirmationVC];

confirmVC.jobOrderId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[json valueForKey:@"joborder_id"]];
confirmVC.sendOutId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[json valueForKey:@"sendout_id"]];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:confirmVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: use  [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];

Comment: In my design, i need to present this view controller

Comment: check this  [self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Thanks. It helped me a lot. I fixed the issue, updated the code like this in AppDelegate [self.navigationController.topViewController presentViewController:confirmVC animated:NO completion:nil]. It is working fine